# Cannot start Julia on Juno+Atom

Tags: julia, atom-editor, juno-ide

I've installed Atom via the ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom
sudo apt install atom
```

then I've installed the Juno IDE via `uber-juno` in the "+Install" section in Atom.

At ths stage, when I try to start Julia from the console in Atom, this strange error appears:

[image]

I'm running

```
Atom    : 1.26.1
Electron: 1.7.11
Chrome  : 58.0.3029.110
Node    : 7.9.0
```

on **Linux Ubuntu 16.04**

Comment: Julia version...?

Comment: Did you installed julia as well? If not I suggest you to download the linux binary from the site, decompress the archive and create symbolic links on /home/[your-username]/bin/

Comment: Of course... a symbolic link has already been created